# Как получить информацию о response через Python парсер?

Tags: python, ajax

Как получить Response через Python код На скриншоте вид моего  Firebug:

[image]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Объясните, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Спринтить всё, что находиться во вкладке Response, ну а дальше планирую вытащить оттуда нужную информацию.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать такой запрос, чтобы мне возратился такой же response, но в мой IDE.

Comment: Вы сами уже пробовали делать такой запрос? Какой библиотекой или парсером вы пользуетесь?
Если вы хотите ответ на свой вопрос, то вам нужно показать вкладку Headers, а не response.

Если вы сами еще не пытались делать запрос, то используйте библиотеки urllib/urllib2, чтобы сформировать точно такой же запрос, как у вас на вкладке Headers.

Comment: парсер Grab, а чтоб подобрать верный запрос использовал requests.get('url'), но запрос так и не подобрал. headers - http://prntscr.com/5xde6g

Comment: Ну вы, наверное, покажите, что вы уже сделали, чтоб можно было сказать, что не так.

Comment: Как я понял, мне нужно сделать правильный запрос, используя определенные get paramemets, чтобы сэмулировать запрос функции ajax и сервер мне вернул, то что возвращает браузеру, import requests  
r = requests.get('http://d.myscore.ru/x/feed/proxy')  
print r.text  
запрос подобран неправильно, естественно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = Grab()
g.setup(headers={

'X-Fsign': 'значение',

})

g.go('запрос')

print g.response.body
```

Получаем response.

Answer (score 0):

Простой GET запрос можно сделать так:

```
import urllib
html_text = urllib.urlopen(your_url).read()
```